# How does a Spark dependency less Model export works?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

Could anyone please explain in simple language how does a Spark model
 export works which is NOT dependent on the Spark cluster during
 predictions?

I mean, if we are using Spark functions like ml.feature.stopwordremover in training in ML pipeline and export it in say, PMML format, how does this function gets regenerated when deployed in production where I don't have a Spark installation. May be when we use JPMML. I went through the PMML wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) but it simply explains the structure of PMML. However no functional description is provided there.

Any good links to articles are welcome.

Comment: i don't understand the reason for downvotes. Please atleast put the reason in comments. It is understandable that some people don't want to write lot of text for a question which requires it, but downvoting would discourage others who wants to give meaningful responses.

Comment: Also, I know this question apparently is not directly related to programming, but in a way it is because understanding the concept is crucial here to write a good model exporting code. Please don't expect everyone to put typical bug questions in SO, like "Oh, there is a bug in this code. I tried this to fix the bug but not working, could you please find it". Conceptual questions should also be allowed.

Comment: PMML only defines an interchange format which is used to represent a specific model. It is up to evaluator, which will differ from target to target, to express the  model using platform specific primitives. Resulting function doesn't have to, and in general is not, equivalent to the input one as it can have different domain and range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please experiment with the [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library (or its [PySpark2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/pyspark2pmml) or [Sparklyr2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sparklyr2pmml) frontends) to see how exactly are different Apache Spark transformers and models mapped to the PMML standard.

For example, the PMML standard does not provide a specialized "remove stopwords" element. Instead, all low-level text manipulation is handled using generic [TextIndex](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/Transformations.html#xsdElement_TextIndex) and [TextIndexNormalization](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/Transformations.html#xsdElement_TextIndexNormalization) elements. The removal of stopwords is expressed/implemented as a regex transformation where they are simply replaced with empty strings. To evaluate such PMML documents, your runtime must only provide basic regex capabilities - there is absolutely no need for Apache Spark runtime or its transformer and model algorithms/classes.

The translation from Apache Spark ML to PMML works surprisingly well (eg. much better coverage than with other translation approaches such as MLeap).